# python pyq4 widget exit after executing the file

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

i have a python project.and i'm new to pyqt4 but i encountered a problem and cant find a solution. My project have a main file called main.py and the content of it is this:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
import setup, modules


class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        file_path = os.path.abspath("form_ui/main_window.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.show()
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Developer contact: admin.unu@protonmail.com')                #message on status bar of main window
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close)                                              #action to close main windows
        self.actionSetup.triggered.connect(setup.setup_gui.setupgui)                               #action to run setup_guy.py
        self.actionUser.triggered.connect(modules.user_form.user_set)                              #action to run user_form.py
        self.actionClient_check.triggered.connect(modules.client_read.client_read_op)              #action to rin client_read.py
        self.actionClient_add.triggered.connect(modules.client_make.client_make_op)                #action to run client_make.py
        self.actionEquipment_add.triggered.connect(modules.add_equipment.add_equipment_op)         #action to run add_equipment.py
        self.actionOrders.triggered.connect(modules.comanda.comanda_def)                           #action to run comanda.py
        self.actionServices.triggered.connect(modules.services.add_services_op)                    #action to run services.py
        self.actionList_data.triggered.connect(modules.list_data.list_data_op)                     #action to run list_data.py
        self.move(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center()- self.rect().center())     #center main windows

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The app is starting and the gui launches. Each action launch a qwidget. This is one qwidget example:

```
import sys,os.path
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

class user_set(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        super(user_set, self).__init__()
        file_path = os.path.abspath("form_ui/user_form.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.show()
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.move(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center() - self.rect().center())
        sys.exit(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = user_set()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When the main window try to run the widget it instantly closes (the widget not main window). i have inserted the line `sys.exit(app)` and the widget runs ok, but in pycharm i get this error `sys.exit(app) NameError: global name 'app' is not defined`. If i try to run only the widget file, the windows appear and exit instantlly and i have to comment de `sys.exit(app)` line.

Does someone have any ideea what i did wrong?  Thank you

EDIT1-------------------------------------------------------------------

his is my main file:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
import setup, modules


class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        file_path = os.path.abspath("form_ui/main_window.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.show()
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Developer contact: admin.unu@protonmail.com')                #message on status bar of main window
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close)                                              #action to close main windows
        self.actionSetup.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog_setup)                               #action to run setup_guy.py
        self.actionUser.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog_user_set)                              #action to run user_form.py
        self.actionClient_check.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog_client_read)              #action to rin client_read.py
        self.actionClient_add.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog_client_make)                #action to run client_make.py
        self.actionEquipment_add.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog_add_equipment)         #action to run add_equipment.py
        self.actionOrders.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog_comanda)                           #action to run comanda.py
        self.actionServices.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog_add_services)                    #action to run services.py
        self.actionList_data.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog_list_data)                     #action to run list_data.py
        self.move(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center()- self.rect().center())     #center main windows


    def run_dialog_user_set(self):
        dialog = modules.user_form.user_set()
        dialog.show()
        dialog.accept()
        sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    # QtGui.QApplication.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My second file is this:

```
import sys,os.path
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

class user_set(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        file_path = os.path.abspath("form_ui/user_form.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.move(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center() - self.rect().center())

# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
#     window = user_set()
#     window.show()
#     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried PYPL solution, and the app error was solved. i tried his last solution but no results, the app is stil closing. i will set a link to a youtube video to see what i mean.

PS: furas solution i couldnt test it, because i did not understand it, i'm new to pyhton and not an native english speaker, sorry.

Youtube link:https://youtu.be/9F2-5NVaqvQ

Comment: You have `sys.exit(app)` inside widget so it has to exit at once. But if you import this code then it doesn't execute `if __name__ == '__main__':` and it doesn't create `app` and `sys.exit(app)` give you error. Put many `print()` in code to see which part is executed. BTW: widgete doesn't have access to `app` created in main file.

Comment: BTW: use `CamelCase` names for classes - `UserSet` - It seems you use class name in `trigger.connect()` but it may expect only functions/methods.

Comment: i'm looking into your comment, try to test it. i'll be back with answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized your superclass twice in a row in both classes!

Change `user_set` superclass to `QtGui.QDialog`

```
import sys,os.path
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic

class user_set(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self) init super [1]
        super(user_set, self).__init__() init super [2] -> GET RID OF THIS !!
        file_path = os.path.abspath("form_ui/user_form.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        self.move(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center() - self.rect().center())
```

You should not call `.show()` in your class `__init__` function! instead create another method where you create a dialog and call your widget from it

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        file_path = os.path.abspath("form_ui/main_window.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Developer contact: admin.unu@protonmail.com')
        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.actionSetup.triggered.connect(setup.setup_gui.setupgui)
        self.actionUser.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog_user_set)
        self.actionClient_check.triggered.connect(modules.client_read.client_read_op)
        self.actionClient_add.triggered.connect(modules.client_make.client_make_op)
        self.actionEquipment_add.triggered.connect(modules.add_equipment.add_equipment_op)
        self.actionOrders.triggered.connect(modules.comanda.comanda_def)
        self.actionServices.triggered.connect(modules.services.add_services_op)
        self.actionList_data.triggered.connect(modules.list_data.list_data_op)
        self.move(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screen().rect().center()- self.rect().center())

    def run_dialog_user_set(self):
        dialog = modules.user_form.user_set()
        dialog.show()
```

Comment: i did your modifications, but the window opens and closes instantly. i change de user_set class to Qdialog. if i uncomment the sys.exit(app) line from user_set class the window opens but the error message in console appears. this is the error:NameError: global name 'app' is not defined, any thoughts?

Comment: Problem somewhat solved, i adjusted your solution a little bit. this is what i use: 
`def run_dialog_user_set(self): dialog = modules.user_form.user_set() dialog.show() sys.exit(dialog.exec_())` . the `user_set` is opening and stai opened but if i close it the main window closes to.

Comment: @BogdanRadu that's might be because you're doing `self.move()` right inside your dialog where you're trying to refer to qappliaction. Instead `.move` your dialog right before you call `dialog.show()` in your `run_dialog_user_set` method : `dialog.move(<positions>)`